# Using one subject to propagate completly different event streams through

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-extensions-js, rxjs

I need to proxy all the different event streams through one subject.

I came up with this code:

```js
var mySubject,
    getObservable;

getObservable = function (subject, eventName) {
    return subject
        .asObservable()
        .filter(function (x) {
            return x.EventName === eventName;
        })
        .flatMap(function (x) {
            if (x.Type === 'onNext') {
                return Rx.Observable.return(x.Data);
            }

            if (x.Type === 'onError') {
                return Rx.Observable.throw(x.Data);
            }

            return Rx.Observable.empty();
        });
};

mySubject = new Rx.Subject();

getObservable(mySubject, 'foo')
    .subscribe(function(x){ 
        console.log('foo onNext ' + x); 
    }, function(x){ 
        console.log('foo onError ' + x); 
    }, function(){ 
        console.log('foo onComplete');
    });

getObservable(mySubject, 'bar')
    .subscribe(function(x){ 
        console.log('bar onNext ' + x); 
    }, function(x){ 
        console.log('bar onError ' + x); 
    }, function(){ 
        console.log('bar onComplete');
    });

mySubject.onNext({Type: 'onNext', EventName: 'foo', Data: 5});
mySubject.onNext({Type: 'onCompleted', EventName: 'foo'});

mySubject.onNext({Type: 'onNext', EventName: 'bar', Data: 5});
mySubject.onNext({Type: 'onError', EventName: 'bar', Data: 'Error message'});
```

Got output:

```js
foo onNext 5

bar onNext 5
bar onError Error message
```

Expected output:

```js
foo onNext 5  
foo onCompleted

bar onNext 5
bar onError Error message
```

For the `bar` event, that works like a charm: `onNext` will be propagated and as soon as the error raises the `onError` function gets called and the event stream finishes. However, I can't get it to work for the `onComplete`.

Whenever a complete notification raises I do see that `Rx.Observable.empty()` gets called but that doesn't cause the subscribers `onComplete` handler to be called. Instead, its calling its `onNext` handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getObservable` function returns an observable that subscribes to a `eventName` event sent through a `subject`.

```js
let getObservable = function (subject, eventName) {
    return Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
        subject
            .asObservable()
            .filter(function(x) {
                return x.EventName === eventName;
            })
            .map(function(x) {
                if (x.Type === 'onNext') {
                    observer.onNext(x.Data);
                }

                if (x.Type === 'onError') {
                    observer.onError(x.Data);
                }

                if (x.Type === 'onCompleted') {
                    observer.onCompleted();
                }

                return x;
            })
            .subscribe();
    });
};
```

This is a working example using data from the original question:

```js
var mySubject,
    getObservable;

getObservable = function (subject, eventName) {
    return Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
        subject
            .asObservable()
            .filter(function(x) {
                return x.EventName === eventName;
            })
            .map(function(x) {
                if (x.Type === 'onNext') {
                    observer.onNext(x.Data);
                }

                if (x.Type === 'onError') {
                    observer.onError(x.Data);
                }
                
                if (x.Type === 'onCompleted') {
                    observer.onCompleted();
                }
                
                return x;
            })
            .subscribe();
    });
};

mySubject = new Rx.Subject();

getObservable(mySubject, 'foo')
    .subscribe(function(x){ 
        console.log('SomethingHappened onNext ' + x); 
    }, function(x){ 
        console.log('SomethingHappened onError ' + x); 
    }, function(){ 
        console.log('SomethingHappened onComplete');
    });


getObservable(mySubject, 'bar')
    .subscribe(function(x){ 
        console.log('DataUpdated onNext ' + x); 
    }, function(x){ 
        console.log('DataUpdated onError ' + x); 
    }, function(){ 
        console.log('DataUpdated onComplete');
    });

mySubject.onNext({Type: 'onNext', EventName: 'foo', Data: 5});
mySubject.onNext({Type: 'onCompleted', EventName: 'foo'});

mySubject.onNext({Type: 'onNext', EventName: 'bar', Data: 5});
mySubject.onNext({Type: 'onError', EventName: 'bar', Data: 'Error message'});
```

```html
<script src='https://rawgit.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/master/dist/rx.all.js'></script>
```

Comment: great work Mike. Still, I fail to see why my initial try didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

in .NET Observable.SelectMany uses Observable.Merge to merge streams together to one composite observable. IMHO Observable.Merge completes only when any of the merged observables are completed.

e.g. http://theburningmonk.com/2010/02/rx-framework-iobservable-merge/

Thats could be the reason for issue.

Comment: yes, could be. But your solution works, too. Consider refactoring it to my updated version because yours returns an empty function as dispose function where as my updated version returns the dispose function. Also it doesn't use the select but the subscribe to do the work. (select should be sideeffect free)

Comment: yes, make sense. Nice idea to combine SignalR with RxJs. Ill play around with times.

Comment: If you are interested in it you can check it out here https://github.com/cburgdorf/SignalR.Reactive